# SqlDataSource select statement syntax error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I'm working on an ASP page for a project, which should provide an interface for the user to maintain information on local little league baseball and softball. I keep getting an error:

Syntax error in FROM clause.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

when attempting to use a SqlDataSource with the following SelectCommand:

```
SELECT tblPlayers.PlayerCode, tblPlayers.First_Name,
                          tblPlayers.Last_Name, tblPlayers.Gender,
                          tblPlayers.Date_of_Birth, tblPlayers.League_age,
                          tblPlayers.InActiveStatus, 
                          tblParentMaster.ParentFirst+' '+tblParentMaster.Parentlast AS Parent_1,
                          tblParentMaster_2.ParentFirst+' '+tblParentMaster_2.ParentLast AS Parent_2,
                          tblPlayers.Birth_Certificate_on_file
                     FROM tblPlayers
                     JOIN tblParentMaster
                       ON tblPlayers.HOHCode = tblParentMaster.ParentCode
                     JOIN tblParentMaster AS tblParentMaster_2
                       ON tblPlayers.Parent2Code = tblParentmaster_2.ParentCode
                    WHERE (tblPlayers.PlayerCode = @PlayerCode)
```

In this code, @PlayerCode is the SelectedValue attribute of a GridView control on the page. I've already declared the ControlParameter for the SqlDataSource with the above SelectCommand:

```
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="selectPlayerGridView" Name="PlayerCode"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

The SQL select statement is being used to populate data into a FormView. I'm not bothering to post the code for the FormView, sine it's a large chunk of code. I'm not brand new to SQL, but I don't have a lot of practical experience, either. Can someone please point out the syntax error? I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the SELECT statement. How are you setting the SelectCommand?

Comment: Have you tried to run the statement in a DBMS client? What engine do you use BTW?

Comment: The SelectCommand is set as an attribute in the opening tag of the SqlDataSource. <asp:SqlDataSource ID="playerDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:littleLeagueConnectionString %>" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:littleLeagueConnectionString.ProviderName %>" There are INSERT, DELETE, AND UPDATE statements, as well. I haven't tried running the command in a DBMS client yet. The database is an .mdb file. Here's the relationship diagram from Access: http://screencast.com/t/10BCQKW6T

Comment: Pastebin of the entire code of the SqlDataSource: http://pastebin.com/L1E2arHS Pastebin of the entire code of the FormView control: http://pastebin.com/pjFYU0jQ

Comment: You tagged Sql-Server and you are saying there is .mdb database that is a MS Access database

Answer (score 0):

AS you said in comment

If you are using .mdb file then it is an `MS Access database` then It should be connected using `OleDb   providers`

and then your query should be like the following

```
SELECT tblPlayers.PlayerCode, tblPlayers.First_Name,
                          tblPlayers.Last_Name, tblPlayers.Gender,
                          tblPlayers.Date_of_Birth, tblPlayers.League_age,
                          tblPlayers.InActiveStatus, 
                          tblParentMaster.ParentFirst & ' ' & tblParentMaster.Parentlast AS Parent_1,
                          tblParentMaster_2.ParentFirst & ' ' & tblParentMaster_2.ParentLast AS Parent_2,
                          tblPlayers.Birth_Certificate_on_file
                     FROM tblPlayers
                     JOIN tblParentMaster
                       ON tblPlayers.HOHCode = tblParentMaster.ParentCode
                     JOIN tblParentMaster AS tblParentMaster_2
                       ON tblPlayers.Parent2Code = tblParentmaster_2.ParentCode
                    WHERE (tblPlayers.PlayerCode = @PlayerCode)
```

Replace `+` with `&`